# C Function returns unexpected values

Tags: c, function

I'm having a problem while using this program, perimetro ( perimeter). I never get the right value. I always get crazy numbers.

This is my code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>
 int perimetro(int v[][3] , int p);
 int main(){
 int v[1][3];
 int i,j,p;
 for (i=0;i<1;i++){
     for (j=0;j<3;j++){
        printf("Digite o tamanho de um dos lados do triangulo :");
        scanf("%d",&v[i][j]);
    }
   }
perimetro(v,p);
 printf("O perimetro corresponde a : %d",p);
return 0;
}



    int perimetro(int v[][3], int p) {
p=0;
p=p+v[0][0]+v[0][1]+v[0][2];
return p;
```

}

Comment: Please correct your indentation. Thank you!

Comment: Your problem is when you call the function. it returns an integer and you won't assign the value to anywhere. Just assign the function's value to p - 'p = perimetro(v,p);'

Comment: As @user3195614 said, although there is another issue in that you're passing in an uninitialized variable `p` as an argument (the value is not being used, but still). May I recommend that you always compile your code with warnings enabled? `-Wall` in GCC or CLang; check your compiler's manual for other vendors.

Comment: Thank you guys, using p=perimetro(v,p), saved me. I'm very newbie with this things but I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
perimetro(v,p);
```

To

```
p=perimetro(v,p);
```

This is done because the function returns the value(perimeter) but you did not store the value in any variable. Passing `p` to the function and modifying it won't modify the value of it in `main`. This is because C uses pass-by-value and a copy of the variable is found in the function.

A better way to do this would be to either pass the address of `p` to the function and use a pointer as the second argument of the function or to pass one argument to the function as the value of the second argument is not used in the function.